# Traditional location for application data in debian linux?

Tags: linux, debian, file-management, services

I'm writing a mobile robotics controller that will run as several daemon services on an embedded (Debian) linux platform. These apps retrieve configuration and log user-data on the filesystem.

To be as compliant with traditional (Debian) Linux as possible, where should I put:

1. the config files
2. the log files

Answer (score 2):

Traditional locations:

- config files: /etc
- log files: /var

Good general reference to the Linux directory structure and important file paths: http://www.tecmint.com/linux-directory-structure-and-important-files-paths-explained/